SQL Server STIntersects returning wrong results
The problem
I am using Azure SQL Database to store tables that have geography data types. In one of these tables, I have geographies of type Polygon and Multipolygon. I have inserted my data from a pandas DataFrame using the geometry's wkt and then geography::STGeomFromText(?, 4326)). I have verified that I can query my data and paint it correctly back in python.
However, I am now trying to create a buffer from a point and finding the intersection between this buffer and the geometries in the table:
BEGIN
    DECLARE @location GEOGRAPHY = GEOGRAPHY::Point(40.4168, -3.7038, 4326);
    DECLARE @buffer GEOGRAPHY = @location.STBuffer(500);

    SELECT column1, geom.STAsText() as geom
    FROM my_schema.my_table
    WHERE geom.STIntersects(@buffer) = 1;
END

The result is always 1, even from geometries that are really far away from the original point.
What I've tried
I have tried correcting some of the geometries using MakeValid(), but the result does not change. An example of such wrong geometry is:
POLYGON ((-1.604360589999942 39.260269826000069, -1.6045030709999537 39.258929008000052, -1.605052293999961 39.253439263000075, -1.6051683319999484 39.250512273000027, -1.6052226829999654 39.250107472000025, -1.6052798829999801 39.249558507000074, -1.6062581329999261 39.246975258000077, -1.606406849999928 39.246490465000079, -1.6067534919999389 39.245368341000074, -1.6069688219999421 39.245028532000049, -1.6076113749999763 39.243008879000058, -1.6081279999999651 39.242077959000028, -1.6086371669999266 39.240939759000071, -1.6100061759999562 39.238505304000057, -1.6110338559999491 39.23692268700006, -1.6121469229999548 39.235710553000047, -1.61223049299997 39.235585413000081, -1.6125533799999516 39.235075661000053, -1.6126331959999334 39.232787967000036, -1.6127879199999597 39.231402235000076, -1.6130749519999767 39.228008744000078, -1.6133330939999269 39.227254937000055, -1.6137814699999353 39.226251139000055, -1.6145765289999758 39.224701781000078, -1.6154262389999303 39.223315268000079, -1.6159553849999497 39.222330398000054, -1.6167405669999653 39.221276531000058, -1.618945546999953 39.218707668000036, -1.6194574709999756 39.218001927000046, -1.6199186269999473 39.217520844000035, -1.6201586149999798 39.216505432000076, -1.6207249639999759 39.215385895000054, -1.6208004209999558 39.215299884000046, -1.6211396259999447 39.214913230000036, -1.6234468209999591 39.213021335000064, -1.625190378999946 39.212113874000067, -1.6262894039999765 39.211586194000063, -1.6264950229999613 39.211138103000053, -1.6273292979999496 39.209931545000074, -1.6279176979999761 39.209451878000039, -1.6289146149999283 39.208814862000054, -1.629584791999946 39.208300162000057, -1.62989515299995 39.207826290000071, -1.6305546209999306 39.207266363000031, -1.6309994929999334 39.206424653000056, -1.6315449969999349 39.204574867000076, -1.6323382589999369 39.20427778700008, -1.6350435199999538 39.20332742800008, -1.6383260099999575 39.202464761000044, -1.6391793599999573 39.202060269000071, -1.6447371089999478 39.199701235000077, -1.6471226949999505 39.198494538000034, -1.6492000959999586 39.19765366300004, -1.6570503329999724 39.200141199000029, -1.6570381609999458 39.201384492000045, -1.6573068879999369 39.203694263000045, -1.6572975709999582 39.204180742000062, -1.6568477549999443 39.205301848000033, -1.6549889539999754 39.208028594000041, -1.654841954999938 39.208450407000043, -1.6548447539999529 39.208909965000032, -1.6550083439999526 39.210047185000064, -1.6554889489999596 39.211566488000074, -1.6555766969999581 39.212432496000076, -1.6557042759999376 39.213028655000073, -1.6555966819999526 39.213811349000025, -1.65578170699996 39.216255278000062, -1.6561274999999682 39.218773216000045, -1.6564489689999391 39.220137493000038, -1.6570319369999424 39.221153359000027, -1.6592881189999389 39.223729304000074, -1.6612496159999637 39.226581148000037, -1.6618544929999644 39.227669334000041, -1.6624849809999773 39.228631685000039, -1.6631853329999444 39.22957682100008, -1.6636745059999498 39.230050961000074, -1.6648515129999737 39.230911392000053, -1.6648970139999619 39.230957034000028, -1.6659467369999561 39.231807007000043, -1.6668429959999571 39.234033864000025, -1.6676574359999563 39.235692043000029, -1.6691306219999547 39.238051622000057, -1.6703067619999388 39.239578798000025, -1.6723718389999362 39.241899975000081, -1.6732963229999314 39.242649381000035, -1.6766949149999277 39.244931652000048, -1.6778152289999753 39.245746300000064, -1.6782142539999541 39.246093212000062, -1.677474363999977 39.246616417000041, -1.6738745069999368 39.250089574000071, -1.6711598339999796 39.252698629000065, -1.6700101929999391 39.252820657000029, -1.6667474549999497 39.250089287000037, -1.6650017919999414 39.248645624000062, -1.6636584669999479 39.248594192000041, -1.65884469599996 39.248223495000047, -1.6567636699999753 39.249181630000066, -1.6552048979999654 39.250100699000029, -1.6548415639999803 39.250312773000076, -1.6529632569999535 39.251570536000031, -1.6501991509999243 39.253088365000053, -1.6491990229999374 39.253265952000049, -1.6476436789999411 39.253392075000079, -1.6469294689999288 39.253771226000026, -1.6455649099999619 39.254818565000051, -1.6446250789999795 39.255474420000041, -1.6425155999999674 39.257287936000068, -1.640851146999978 39.258854316000054, -1.6405486389999737 39.258913895000035, -1.6392525589999423 39.258808689000034, -1.6373290459999339 39.258786198000053, -1.6356592329999557 39.258829683000044, -1.6337248409999461 39.258771001000071, -1.6322999829999389 39.259925629000065, -1.6319743509999398 39.26176887500003, -1.6305164939999486 39.267590452000036, -1.6283389639999655 39.268096405000051, -1.6203154709999694 39.26997489200005, -1.6156715159999635 39.270928910000066, -1.6147017309999683 39.270728160000033, -1.6133250759999669 39.27058562600007, -1.6098750719999657 39.270364271000062, -1.6078159329999266 39.270150449000027, -1.6063014679999696 39.269943114000057, -1.6052976909999757 39.269705854000051, -1.6020478649999745 39.268747799000039, -1.602369375999956 39.267733527000075, -1.6026627569999619 39.266385501000059, -1.6029213339999728 39.26562274500003, -1.6033150409999735 39.265059794000081, -1.6043328599999427 39.263999761000036, -1.6052175999999463 39.262055140000029, -1.6052022489999445 39.261658471000032, -1.6049266939999711 39.260943376000057, -1.604360589999942 39.260269826000069))

I feel pretty lost, I feel that maybe the geometries in my table are incorrect, but it would really help if you had any insight.

Solved! My polygons were not correctly oriented, so every distance calculation was off. The solution, as explained in this comment, was to reorient the polygon before calculating the distance.
